# Connecting to Google Cloud Endpoints from Google App Engine for Java

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been testing Cloud Endpoints for a few days now and am able to access cloud endpoints locally.  However, when I deploy to app engine I can't seem to navigate to the endpoint URL.  I get a 404 error when trying to access http://myappname.mydomainname.appspot.com/_ah/api/contact/v1/contact/myname.  If I try to access locally I can view the response.  When I look at the app engine admin logs I see the status "Successfully updated API configuration".  What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must update your **APINAME-v1.api** file in war/WEB-INF?

```
{
  "extends" : "thirdParty.api",
  "root" : "https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api",
  "name" : "bbwjob",
  "version" : "v1",
  "adapter" : {
    "bns" : "http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/spi",
    "deadline" : 10.0,
    "type" : "lily"
  },
 ...
}
```

Please update the root and BNS value and put the real APPID. I experience your problem and since update update that file and re-upload. That makes my jump.

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: The actual problem was that I needed to use myapp.appspot.com instead of myappid.myapp.appspot.com.